# Using "jenseits" in a statement

Tags: usage, preposition

In learning prepositions, here is my attempt to use "*jenseits*".

*Jenseits der Gedanken, brummt Wissenheit.*

The English version I have in mind is "On the other side of thought, wisdom hums".

I have attempted a straight translation, so happy to use a better construction that captures the nuance better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A few things: 1. No comma in German after preposition+noun. 2. _wisdom_ in German is _Weisheit_. 3. _to hum_ can be translated as _summen_, as well. 4. What is the intended meaning of _On the other side of thought, wisdom hums._?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the feedback and corrections.  The sentence is my attempt in taking a similar Sufi saying and "playing" with it from a language learning standpoint.  The meaning for me:  Don't think too much, be in the present.

Comment: I think your sentence alone would not meet much understanding with Germans. And I think that jenseits is becoming rare in spoken language apart from some fixed formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your translation is pretty straight forward. To try to translate it differently might add complications that are not necessary and could eventually even cloud the meaning of what you try to say.
The only correction I have is to remove the comma. Unless I am mistaken, in German you wouldn't put a comma there (see here: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma).

Answer (score 2):

'Jenseits' can also mean 'beyond': 'Jenseits von Gut und Böse' => "Beyond Good and Evil', so I'd go with "beyond thought, wisdom hums" for your translation.